# Printing rss using PHP?

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to use an rss feed from a domain that does not have a crossdomain file and because of that I am going to use a web service in the middle where I will be just getting the rss feed from a url (let's say the url is: www.example.com/feed) and then just print it to a page.

The service would work like: www.mywebservice.com/feed.php?word=something) and that will just go print the rss feed for: www.example.com/feed&q=word).

I used:

```
<?php

$word = $_GET["word"];

$ch=curl_init("http://example.com/feed.php?word=".$word."");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print $data;

?>
```

But this did not work, it gives me (SYSTEM ERROR: we're sorry but a serious error has occurred in the system). I am on shared hosting
Any help?

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: I am not sure how to get the xml feed from the website then print it, so as a start, getting the xml feed would be a good start then is printing it as easy as: print $xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at the end I ended up doing this:

```
$word = $_GET["word"];

$url = "http://www.example.com/feed.php?q=".$word;

$curl = @curl_init ($url);

@curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
@curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
@curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
@curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

$source = @curl_exec ($curl);
@curl_close ($curl);
print $source;
```

I hope this is considered as an answer not an edit (if an edit please tell me so I can just delete this answer and edit the post)

Answer (score 2):

The [`readfile`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) function *reads a file and writes it to the output buffer.*

```
readfile('http://example.com/feed.rss');
```

> A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen wrappers have been enabled. See fopen()  for more details on how to specify the filename. See the List of Supported Protocols/Wrappers for links to information about what abilities the various wrappers have, notes on their usage, and information on any predefined variables they may provide.

If you need to do anything with the XML, use one of [PHP's many XML libraries](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php), preferably [`DOM`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php), but there is also [`SimpleXml`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) or [`XMLReader`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php). As an alternative, you could use [`Zend_Feed` from the Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.html) as a standalone component to work with the RSS feed.

If you cannot enable [`allow_url_fopen`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) on your server, [try cURL like Matchu suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206068/printing-rss-using-php/3206135#3206135) or [go with Artefacto's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206068/printing-rss-using-php/3206124#3206124).

Comment: the problem with read file is that it gives me the error (URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration). I tried it but not sure how to either fix the configuration or in fact, use something else

Comment: @use You have to enable allow_url_fopen or work around it with fsockopen/curl.

Comment: @user Write a script with only `<?php phpinfo();` and see if curl is listed there. If it's not, you cannot use it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider doing this with [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) (using the `P` flag) or setting up a reverse proxy with [`ProxyPass`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass).

Answer (score 1):

Since you say you can't do the fancy URL-file-opening shortcuts due to server restrictions, you will need to use [PHP's cURL module](http://php.net/curl) to send an HTTP request.

Comment: I am using that (please take a look at the edited post above) but it is not working for some reason.

Comment: @user220755 - sounds like the error is, in fact, serious. That code looks to me like it should work. Try talking with your hosting provider about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to also parse XML and process it further, be sure to look into [SimpleXML](http://php.net/simplexml). Let's you parse and manipulate the feed.